# Problem calling action in browser

Tags: extension

I have made an extension that creates an action. The action has been created and is in the database with an ID of 34. But when I go to the following URL:

```
http://mywebsite.com/index.php?ACT=34
```

I get an error page saying:

```
Error
The action you have requested is invalid.
```

The method name stored in the database is post_job and I have this method defined in my extension class. Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have this method defined in my extension class

There it is! Action methods are only valid if they belong to a module (either `mod.classname.php` or `mcp.classname.php`). They will not work if they live in an extension or plugin.